# How to check the date format in given structure

Tags: c#

I have passing a date in query string as the format of 02-2014.and using this date I done the search.It is working and the result is perfect .but when I change the query string value in  the browser then the error will showing.In this condition I need only some message,So how can we check the query string date value is in correct format.my code is

```
string dateToSearch = HttpContext.Current.Request["date"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateToSearch))
{
    dateToSearch = dateToSearch.Trim();
    string year = null;
    string month = null;
    var dates = dateToSearch.Split("-".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (dates.Length > 0)
    {
        month = dates[0];
        year = dates[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: try to get "DateTime" value? could you please edit subject? May be solution can be easier than your code.

Comment: "then the error will showing" doesn't tell us anything about what's wrong. I suspect you want to check `if (dates.Length == 2)`

Answer (score 5):

Just use `DateTime.TryParseExact` with the format string `MM-yyyy`. This will tell you whether your input string is in the format you specified and if so, it returns the parsed DateTime object via an out parameter.

Comment: While that's tempting, given that there's no day being specified, I'm not sure what happens if (say) the current date is the 30th and you parse 02-2014...

Comment: As no day is specified, the parser simply assumes it is the 1st of the specified month 0:00:00.00000

Comment: Yup, just validated that myself. Deleting my answer. I'd recommend specifying CultureInfo.InvariantCulture though - you probably don't want to use the current culture's default calendar.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'd rather say that the choice of the CultureInfo is rather specific to the application. In this scenario it might be a good idea to take the culture info that was specified in the http request.

Comment: @Georg actually my query string is like this.

http://wsa09:702/events/?date=01-2014&keyword=test

and it will produce the output,But when some one change the querystring value in browser like

http://wsa09:702/events/?date=2014&keyword=test

it showing  error.so I need to check before split the query string is in correct format  ????

Comment: @Arun As far as I can see, these links are inaccessible, probably protected behind a firewall.

Comment: @Georg: Unless this is actually typed in by the user, it would be better specified as the invariant culture. Where possible, it's best to avoid taking textual user input for dates/times anyway - use a GUI picker, and then format the value into a common format (e.g. ISO-8601) for transport.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "MM'-'yyyy",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None,
                           out date))
{
   // Success
}
else
{
   // Parse failed
}
```